# JavaFX 2 - Autoscroll to last item in exceeded toolbar

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I am creating File Manager like Miller column app for windows in JavaFX for learning purpose.
Check the screenshot below:
[image: Miller Column File Manager App]

As you can see, when toolbar exceeds, there comes a double arrow button for more items to select from popup.

I already did auto scroll for miller column, which works as expected.

```
scrollPane.hvalueProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty());
```

**I would like to auto scroll toolbar to last item and show double arrow on left side.**
I am adding adding clickable buttons in toolbar for traversing like manual BreadCumBar.
*Tried ControlsFX BreadCumBar, it doesn't even show arrows or popup when exceeds, Bug here : https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/810/no-double-arrow-popup-like-when.*
**If its not possible to do so with toolbar, I would like to know how to customize toolbar popup only via css. Or any other way that improve usability easiness.** 
Also I would love to know suggestions for whole app from expert designers.

Thanks.

Comment: "I hope someone report this bug to them." That someone could be you.

Comment: @M.leRutte thanks, updated question.

Comment: please provide  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are doing and how it doesn't match your requirement